# How to get same result without need to use js2py

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want output 355901652 without using js2py,
How to get same result without need to use js2py

```
import js2py
o = 'How To Solve This'
a = 0
f = js2py.eval_js('function $(a, o){for (var m = 0; m < o.length; m++){a = (a << 5) - a + o.charCodeAt(m),a &= a}return a}')
print(f(a, o))
# return : 355901652

m = 0
while m < len(o):
  a = (a << 5) - a + ord(o[m])
  a &= a
  m += 1
print(a)
# return : 55070035549200009615810772
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like JavaScript uses 32-bit integers, while Python's `int`s are almost unbounded. So you'll need to constraint `a` to 32 bits:

```
m = 0
while m < len(o):
  a = (a << 5) - a + ord(o[m])
  a &= a
  a &= (1 << 32) - 1  # restrict `a` to 32 bits
  m += 1
print(a)
```

Output:

```
355901652
```

In terms of algorithm correctness, Python is outputting the correct result because it can handle such huge integers, but JavaScript's integers are overflowing at some point, and you're starting to get garbage results, that is, 355901652 isn't the correct answer.